# What are different type of gamers and how it is helpful for game testing?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, regression-testing, security-testing

What are the different types of gamers? How can we categorize it? How is it helpful for performing game testing?

Sorry to post this question under an irrelevant tag.

Comment: This sounds like a question better suited for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You might want to change "types of gamers" to "personas of gamers".  Using personas in testing is very useful to help design your tests to match typical users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean "what are the different personas of gamers?", here is a start. You can take this as a start then validate with your marketing team - they surely use personas in marketing, and likely have actual data to help inform the personas.

**Hardcore gamer**: male, 14-18, plays multiple consoles frequently with the same group of friends. Plays 5 hours on weekdays and 10 hours on weekends.

**Noob**: male or female, playing the game when visiting their hardcore gamer relative

**Casual**: Adult who has the latest console and plays a couple of hours a week.

With personas, you can design tests to appeal to each type of persona. For example, the hardcore gamer is going to skip the tutorials and jump right in. While the noob will likely spend all the time in the introductory sections.

Hope this helps get you started.